# CSS Horizontal Space Issue between 2 Divs

Tags: css

With the top-feature-faq and the mid-feature-faq there is excessive width between the 2 divs.

Here is the CSS for that:  In this example the top-feature-faq has position:relative

```
#top-feature-faq 
{
height:330px;
width: 800px;
margin: 12px 0 0 17px;
background: red;
position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
text-align: left;
}
#mid-feature-faq
{
margin:350px 0 0 17px;
width:800px;
height:318px;
background-color:Olive;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
clear: both;
}

<div id="top-feature-faq">
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
<<div id="mid-feature-faq">
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. You have a clearing div between the containers on the page with the problem. That means that the 350px top margin starts at the clearing div instead of the top of the container.

Remove:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Between top-feature-faq and mid-feature-faq or change the top margin on mid-feature-faq.

Answer (score 0):

First off, before I say why it's not working - why are you using absolute positioning? It's unnecessary, and it's what's causing the problem. The CSS isn't the cause of it - it's because of improper mathematics.

`#top-feature` = 330px height + 12px top-margin. (absolutely positioned)

`#mid-feature` = 350px top-margin.

If you change the top margin for `#top-feature` to 20px, or the top margin for `#mid-feature` to 342px, the problem solves itself.

EDIT:

> `#top-feature 
> {
> height:330px;
> width: 848px;
> margin: 12px 0 0 17px;
> /*background: #E4EAEF;*/
> background: orange;
> text-align: left;
> }
> #mid-feature
> {
> margin:0 0 0 17px;
> width:848px;
> height:318px;
> background-color:Olive;
> position:relative;
> overflow:hidden;  
> }`

Comment: While absolute positioning is unnecessary here, the problem is not the math, it's the clearing div. He's got 350px of extra space, not 8px.

Comment: However I have another issue now with the width. I will edit this question

Comment: So, do you need to have the top-feature floated, then? I'm not understanding how you want to position these. If you keep the `float:left;` property on the top-feature div, then just add `clear:both;` to your mid-feature div. Is there some reason that you'll need it to work specifically if you remove mid-feature?

Comment: Yes for other pages Im not going to need a mid-feature.  I updated the photos, the divs should appear beneath each other, which is what takes place when I have 2 divs present.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What should work is just to take the original `#top-feature` style, as-is, but remove the `position: absolute;` attribute, and then remove the top-margin from any elements below it. That way, they will line up exactly with each other, they won't change the width, and it maintain its height as usual. I'll put the code in my original post.

Comment: Yes but the issue is with top-feature-faq which does have its position set to relative.  This is the 2nd photo.  When I only use top-feature-faq, the bottom-wrap div doenst flow below.  However when I do use top-feature-faq along with mid-feature-faq, then the bottom-wrap will appear below the 2 divs correct.

Comment: Ah, ok. Does it need to be floated left? If I use some sample code (using your CSS, and add more other unstyled content after), it behaves normally if I remove the float.

Comment: When you use the float property, an element is taken out of the normal flow of rendering, and adding extra content will prefer to either overlap with it, or to render alongside it. Declaring a floated element to have such a large width was probably the cause of that odd scenario. Generally, if you're not creating columns or making navigation bars, float isn't the right property to use.

Comment: Good idea - neither of them seem like they'll be necessary in order to get the top-feature to act like you need it to. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: by removing the top-margin from any elements below the top-feature-faq resolved the issue.  Now they line up exactly with each other

Answer (score 0):

Part of problem existed because  was not within top-feature-faq

```
<div id="top-feature-faq">
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mid-feature-faq">
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
</div>
```